# Trying to use jQuery to horizontally distribute elements of different sizes in a <div>

Tags: jquery, alignment

I'm trying to use jQuery to space these elements apart equally.  As you can see, I'm totaling up the widths of the objects and subtracting by the width of the surrounding DIV to find the empty space.  Then I divide that empty space and space out each element by that amount (via right margin).  Here is the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/spaceninja/baQNA/

My question is (note: I am using this as a learning opportunity because I know there are other methods of doing this) why must I subtract 4 in the following line for it to work?  I thought doing the Math.floor would round it down enough, but there are still approx 4 pixels that are breaking this down to the next line.  If you take the -4 out of the following line, it breaks and I don't know why.

`var spacer = (Math.floor(remaining / 4) -4 );`

Here is the HTML:

```
<div>
    <span>Short</span>
    <span>A Very Very Long One Is Right Here</span>
    <span>Short</span>
    <span>Short</span>
    <span>Short</span>        
</div>
```

And here is the jQuery:

```
var measurements = 0;
for (var i=0; i<=4; i++) {
    measurements += $('span').eq(i).width();
}
var totalWidth = $('div').width();
var remaining = 0;
remaining = totalWidth - measurements;
var spacer = (Math.floor(remaining / 4) -4 );
for (var i=0; i<=3; i++) {
    $('span').eq(i).css('margin-right', spacer);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's cause of space characters between your spans

```
<div><span>Short</span><span>A Very Very Long One Is Right Here</span><span>Short</span><span>Short</span><span>Short</span></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/r043v/baQNA/7/

Comment: Oh!  Brilliant, thank you so much!  I'm glad I don't have to re-write the whole thing and that I was almost there!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look on my [example](http://sandbox.zije.sk/js/index.php) or [second one](http://sandbox.zije.sk/js/more.php). Maybe inspires you. There is a lot of mess in my code ;)

Content of [sandbox.zije.sk/js/index.php](http://sandbox.zije.sk/js/index.php) :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>JS</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery.js"></script>
        <style>
            body{ padding:0; margin:0; }
            div.rect{ float:left; }
            div.wrapper{ width:900px; height:400px; background: red; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php foreach(range(1,12) as $v) echo '<div class="rect" style="background:#'.rc().'"></div>'; ?>
    </body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
function mod(a, n) {
    return a - (n * Math.floor(a/n));
}
function adjust(c){
    var h = window.innerHeight;
    var w = window.innerWidth;
    var ss = w>h?h:w;
    var ls = w>h?w:h;
    var cnt = $(c).length;

    var i = 1;
    var step = 0.01;
    var box_strana;
    var box_obsah;
    var wrapper_obsah;
    var wrapper_obsah_ef;
    var limit = 5000;
    var index = 0;
    while(true){
        if(index++>limit) break;
        box_strana = ss/i;
        box_obsah = box_strana*box_strana;
        wrapper_obsah = h*w;
        wrapper_obsah_ef = (h-mod(h,box_strana))*(w-mod(w,box_strana));
        if((cnt*box_obsah)<=wrapper_obsah_ef) break;
        i = parseFloat(parseFloat(i) + parseFloat(step));
    }
    console.log(h);
    console.log(box_strana);
    console.log(parseInt(box_strana));
    console.log(mod(h,parseInt(box_strana)));
    console.log(mod(h,parseInt(box_strana)));
    console.log(parseInt(mod(h,parseInt(box_strana))/parseInt(h/parseInt(box_strana))));
    $(c).width(parseInt(box_strana)).height(parseInt(box_strana))
        .css('paddingRight',parseInt(mod(w,parseInt(box_strana))/parseInt(w/parseInt(box_strana))))
        .css('paddingBottom',parseInt(mod(h,parseInt(box_strana))/parseInt(h/parseInt(box_strana))));
};
$(document).ready(function(){
    adjust('.rect');
});
</script>

<?php
function rc(){
    mt_srand((double)microtime()*1000000);
    $c = '';
    while(strlen($c)<6){
        $c .= sprintf("%02X", mt_rand(0, 255));
    }
    return $c;
}

?>
```

Content of [sandbox.zije.sk/js/more.php](http://sandbox.zije.sk/js/more.php) :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>JS</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery.js"></script>
        <style>
            body{ padding:0; margin:0; }
            div.rect{ float:left; }
            div.wrapper{ width:900px; height:400px; background: red; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php foreach(range(1,600) as $v) echo '<div class="rect" style="background:#'.rc().'"></div>'; ?>
    </body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
function mod(a, n) {
    return a - (n * Math.floor(a/n));
}
function adjust(c){
    var h = window.innerHeight;
    var w = window.innerWidth;
    var ss = w>h?h:w;
    var ls = w>h?w:h;
    var cnt = $(c).length;

    var i = 1;
    var step = 0.01;
    var box_strana=1;
    var box_obsah;
    var wrapper_obsah;
    var wrapper_obsah_ef;
    var limit = 5000;
    var index = 0;
    while(true){
        if(index++>limit) break;
        box_obsah = box_strana*box_strana;
        wrapper_obsah = h*w;
//        wrapper_obsah_ef = (h-mod(h,box_strana))*(w-mod(w,box_strana));
        wrapper_obsah_ef = parseInt((h-mod(h,box_strana))*(w-mod(w,box_strana)));
        if(parseInt(cnt*box_obsah)>wrapper_obsah_ef){ box_strana--; break; }
//        console.log()
        box_strana++;
    }
    $(c).width(parseInt(box_strana)).height(parseInt(box_strana))
        .css('paddingRight',parseInt(mod(w,parseInt(box_strana))/parseInt(w/parseInt(box_strana))))
        .css('paddingBottom',parseInt(mod(h,parseInt(box_strana))/parseInt(h/parseInt(box_strana))));
};
$(document).ready(function(){
    adjust('.rect');
    //$(window).on('resize', function(){ adjust('.rect') });
});
</script>



<?php
function rc(){
    mt_srand((double)microtime()*1000000);
    $c = '';
    while(strlen($c)<6){
        $c .= sprintf("%02X", mt_rand(0, 255));
    }
    return $c;
}

?>
```